# How to get data from blueprintjs table

Tags: javascript, html-table, blueprint, blueprintjs

I have created a blueprintjs table, and I want to be able to get it's data in JSON format. I do not want to get all the columns. Specific ones only and I only way them row by row. This
is the format I am talking about:

```
{
     "Campaign": "5",
     "Date Sent": "5 days ago"
}
```

This is the way I have currently rendered my table. I have a button above that will call a javascript function that I wish to do this functionality. On the blueprintjs table documentation, I couldn't find anything related to actually parsing the table. I only found functions relating to just getting data such as # of rows etc.

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { length } = data;
    return (
      <Table
        numRows={length}
      >
        <Column name="Campaign" cellRenderer={this.renderCell} />
        <Column name="Date Sent" cellRenderer={this.renderCell} />
        <Column name="Queueing" cellRenderer={this.renderCell} />
        <Column name="Sent" cellRenderer={this.renderCell} />
        <Column name="Open" cellRenderer={this.renderCell} />
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Blueprint [table documentation](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table):

> The table is data-agnostic. It doesn't store any data internally, so it is up to you to bind the table to your data.

So can get the data directly from the `data` that you pass as props.

For example to select some cells and get a "Copy" button see this demo: https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table/features.sorting

There is also a [`getCellClipboardData` in the table API](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table/api) that allows your users to do mod+c for copy/paste. The way it works is that you get row and column parameters and then just retrieve that data.

I've made an example for you if your data is a data[row][column], with mod+c copy/paste for selected cells and a button that "extracts" first and second column.

```
import React from "react";
import "@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
import "@blueprintjs/table/lib/css/table.css";
import { Button } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { Cell, Column, Table } from "@blueprintjs/table";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    [1, "2 days ago", 3],
    [4, "5 days ago", 6]
  ];

  const getCellData = (rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) => {
    return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
  };

  const cellRenderer = (rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) => (
    <Cell>{`${data[rowIndex][columnIndex]}`}</Cell>
  );

  const columns = ["Campaign", "Date Sent", "Queueing"].map(
    (element: string, index: number) => {
      return <Column key={index} name={element} cellRenderer={cellRenderer} />;
    }
  );

  const extractData = () => {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var myData = {
        Campaign: data[i][0],
        "Date Sent": data[i][1]
      };
      results.push(myData);
    }

    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(results);
    alert(myJSON);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Table numRows={data.length} getCellClipboardData={getCellData}>
        {columns}
      </Table>
      <Button onClick={extractData}>"Copy first and second column"</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wozniak-djk9d?file=/src/App.tsx